# How to update a bootstrap table cell and write the data to a database

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to update a field in a bootstrap table for all selected rows, and write that value back to the database.  I've found it easy enough to get the selected rows, but stuck on how to write this data both to the table and make a call back to the server to write the data to the database.

I'm using asp.net core 2.2 with razor pages and entity framework.

```
var setting = "Some data value";

for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    selected[i].excluded = setting;

    $table.bootstrapTable('updateCell', {
        index: *** how get the row index***,
        field: 'excluded',
        value: setting
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the specified row: `$table.bootstrapTable('updateRow', {index: 1, row: row})` , the update code sample will like :

```
$('#update').click(function () {
    $('input[name="selectItemName"]:checked').each(function () {

    $('#table').bootstrapTable('updateRow', {index: $(this).data('index'),  row: {
        id: 123,
        name: 'Item ' + 123,
        price: '$' + 123
    }});
    })

})
```

Table :

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


<button id="update" class="btn btn-secondary">Update value</button>
<table
id="table"
data-toggle="table"
data-select-item-name="selectItemName"
data-url="json/data1.json"
data-pagination="true"
data-toolbar="#show">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
    <th data-field="id">ID</th>
    <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
    <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

The other part is saving data to database , you can use ajax to call server side function with the updated information , that is lots of code samples such as [this sample](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) and [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996432/mvc-core-use-ajax-to-post-data-and-refresh-a-section-on-the-page) .

Comment: I couldn't get your example to work as $(this).data returned undefined. I've added an answer for how I've got it working. It doesn't work quite like I would have expected but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (excluding the ajax bit), bit puzzled as to why I need to do this though `selected[i][field] = setting;`

```
<table id="table"
       data-url="api/entities"
       data-search="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-undefined-text=""
       data-cache="false"
       data-data-field="entityName"
       class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed text-nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-checkbox="true" title="Select all"></th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="entityName" data-formatter="linkFormatter" data-class="entityName overflowTooltip">Entity Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="entityTypeDescription">Entity Type</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="excluded" data-formatter="checkedFormatter" class="text-center">Excluded</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="forceLoad" data-formatter="checkedFormatter" class="text-center">Force Load</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="dateReplicated" data-formatter="dateFormatter">Last Replicated</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="durationFormatted">Duration</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="replicationStatus">Status</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="rowsUpdated">Rows<br />Updated</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="rowsDeleted">Rows<br />Deleted</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="message" data-formatter="messageFormatter" data-class="message overflowTooltip">Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

async function toggleCheckedItem(handler, field, setting) {
    var selected = $table.bootstrapTable('getSelections');

    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        // Why do I need to do this???
        selected[i][field] = setting;

        const result = await callAjax(`/Index?handler=${handler}&entityName=${selected[i].entityName}&${field}=${setting}`);

        $table.bootstrapTable('updateCellByUniqueId', {
            id: selected[i].entityName,
            field: field,
            value: setting
        });
    }
}

$('#li-set-exclude').click(async function () {
    toggleCheckedItem('Exclude', 'excluded', false);
})
```